# Aggregation Execution Stats (Mongo)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I can see in the documentation that `explain("executionStats")` is available for some of the mongo queries which is really helpful but I can't see such utility for the aggregation query, apart from the `explain` flag which doesn't give much. Is there a plan to integrate the full overview in the aggregation query too?

Answer (score 6):

This function can be applied to aggregate queries, it just needs to be called before the `.aggregate()` function, and with `'executionStats'`, otherwise you will only get details on the query's pipeline and not it's execution.

`db.collection.explain('executionStats').aggregate([..]);`

Comment: I tried this but I got the same result as running the `explain` after the `.aggregate` call.